# DRIVING_SITE Oracle Hint with One Remote Table in the script

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there any advantage of using DRIVING_SITE hint when accessing data from only one remote table. The execution plan remains same with and without the hint.

```
SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(REMOTE_TABLE) */ distinct a.COL1_NB, a.COL2_TX, a.COL3_TX
FROM REMOTE_TABLE@DASH a
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN A.HSTRY_EFCTV_DT AND HSTRY_XPRTN_DT
```

The Remote_table have close to 2M data and the resultset expected to have around 300K records.

Comment: Hints need to reference the table aliases.  Regardless of the meaning of the hint, it won't possibly work without changing it to `/*+ DRIVING_SITE(A) */`.

Comment: @JonHeller Jon, thanks for this point as I had a similar encounter on 11.2 database. However, from `12.2` it seems Oracle internally uses an alias with same name of table **if an alias does not exist**. And hint works with table name. Although, I couldn't find any mention of this change of behavior in online documentation. Of course, if an alias is used for the table, then it should be used in the hint as well. That's what I assume, without any official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  If you are only querying objects in the remote database, it is highly unlikely that the optimizer would generate a plan where the local site was the driving site.  If you aren't seeing the query plan change, that implies that this query likely isn't one of the rare ones that the optimizer would screw up.

I'd strongly suggest removing the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following query in an Oracle R12 procedure:

```
SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(FFUSA_MISSING_DOCS) */ *
FROM FFUSA_MISSING_DOCS@EBS_ONBASE FFUSA_MISSING_DOCS
WHERE "Renewal Date" >= DATE '2018-08-01' OR "Renewal Date" IS NULL;
```

EBS_ONBASE is a database link to MS SQL. I can't get it to filter on the remote database (where equivalent queries take 2 minutes instead of 12+ and return a lot fewer rows). So I personally would strongly suggest keeping the hint and trying to figure out how to get Oracle to listen to you long enough to have them support sending simple filters to remote non-Oracle databases. Here's the explain plan showing how it returns all the data then tries to filter:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |IN-OUT|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |              |   195 |   277K|   200   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|*  1 |  FILTER          |              |   195 |   277K|   200   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   2 |   REMOTE         | MISSING_DOCS |       |       |            |          | EBS_O~ | R->S |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("Renewal Date" IS NULL OR "Renewal Date">=TO_DATE(' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Remote SQL Information (identified by operation id):
----------------------------------------------------

   2 - SELECT {column list} FROM 
       "MISSING_DOCS" (accessing 'EBS_ONBASE' )
```